# TypeError: 'Game' object is not callable

Tags: python, class, typeerror

I am just starting out with object-oriented programming and I am trying to make a game about taking care of a character.

Here is part of my code:

```
class Game(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.hunger = 30
        self.thirst = 30
        self.fun = 30
        self.energy = 30
.........................    
def new_character():
    name = input("Name your character: ")
    name = Game()
    name()
```

But when I run this, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Virtual Human Simulator.py", line 185, in <module>
    new_character_init()
  File "C:\Python34\Virtual Human Simulator.py", line 182, in new_character_init
    name()
TypeError: 'Game' object is not callable
```

I have been searching the internet for people who might have asked that question, but all I got was Type errors with modules and data types, not with classes, and the documentation doesn't help at all.
What is the cause of this problem and how to resolve it?

Comment: name is an instance of Game class not a method, what are you trying yo do?

Comment: As Padraic said, you can not call an instance as a method unless you implements a `__call__` function in it's class definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error points out, you're trying to use the newly created object as a function. `name()` . Unless your class has the `__call__` method defined, this will fail. It would probably be more useful to tell us what you're trying to achieve